# Separation of Variables (PDEs): What about $0$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> **Question:** [See the context given below.]
>
> $\rm\color{#c00}{(a)}$ When we divide by the functions $T$ and $X$ to obtain $(1)$, aren't we assuming that the functions will be non-vanishing on their whole domain (otherwise it doesn't make sense)?
>
> $\rm\color{#c00}{(b)} $I know that when we solve the separable ODE
>   $$
> y'=f(x)g(y),
> $$
>   by dividing by $g(y)$, relatively general conditions on $g$ (continuity is not enough) will assure that either $g(y)\equiv0$ or $g(y)\neq0$ on the whole domain.
>
> But here, for example, $X_4$ given by $(2)$ is $0$ at $x=\frac{L}{2}$. So, there is no analogous comforting result?
>
> $\rm\color{#c00}{(c)}$ Is there some kind of "continuous extension" of the solutions on $(0,\frac{L}{2})$ and $(\frac{L}{2},L)$? What when $n$ is general?
>
> One can always verify that the final solution obtained by the applying the method *is*, indeed, a solution. But, I'm interested in understanding why the method works.

**Context:** Suppose you want to solve the following homogeneous heat equation problem:
$$
\begin{cases}
u_t-ku_{xx}=0\quad(0<x<L,t>0),\\
u(0,t)=u(L,t)=0\quad(t\geq0),\\
u(x,0)=f(x)\quad(0\leq x\leq L)
\end{cases}
$$
with the compatibility condition $f(0)=f(L)=0$ satisfied.

Proceeding by separation of variables, writing $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$, the usual argument is that one is led to
$$
\frac{T_t}{kT}=\frac{X_{xx}}{X}\tag{1},
$$
which must be satisfied for all admissible couple $(x,t)$, so that the LHS and the RHS must be constant. One is then led to Sturm-Liouville problems and one can show that the eigenvalue-eigenvector couples for the resulting problem in $X$ are
$$
(\lambda_n,X_n):=\left(\frac{n^2\pi^2}{L2},\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)\right)\quad(n\geq1)\tag{2}.
$$

Comment: What did you think of the answer below?

Comment: @JohnD To be honest I prefer Christian Blatter's point of view. It completely ignores this issue. I wonder why he called the method a "heuristic" argument, because "heuristic" implies that it is not totally rigorous. Anyway, as for your answer, I don't understand when you say that on $Z$ we already know that $(0)$ is satisfied trivially. If a function is $0$ at $x$ it doesn't mean that its derivatives are $0$ at $x$... Also I understand that $u$ might not vanish even if some of the $u_n$ do, but still the question applies to the individual $u_n$, and $X_n$ does vanish at some points...

Comment: I edited paragraph 3 to add the details of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While dividing by $X(x)T(t)$ is a quick and easy heuristic way to arrive at the desired ODEs for $x\mapsto X(x)$ and $t\mapsto T(t)$ one can do without division whatsoever.

In the case of the heat equation $u_t-k u_{xx}=0$ we hope that there are some solutions of the form $$u:\quad{\mathbb R}\times{\mathbb R}\to{\mathbb R},\qquad(x,t)\mapsto u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)\ .\tag{1}$$
This "Ansatz" immediately leads to the condition
$$X(x)\dot T(t)-k X''(x)T(t)=0\quad\forall x\>,\ \forall t\ .\tag{2}$$
A usable such solution will have a point $x_0\in{\mathbb R}$ with $X(x_0)\ne0$. Putting $x:=x_0$ in $(2)$ we see that the function $t\mapsto T(t)$ then would have to satisfy the constant coefficient ODE
$$\dot T(t)-{kX''(x_0)\over X(x_0)}\>T(t)=0\qquad\forall t\ ,$$
or $\dot T-\lambda T=0$, with a certain  (real or complex) constant $\lambda$, but no a priori condition on the value of this $\lambda$. The general solution of the latter ODE is $T(t)=Ce^{\lambda t}$, which then can be entered into $(2)$. This leads to the simpler condition 
$$\lambda X(x)-k X''(x)=0\qquad\forall x\tag{3}$$
involving only the function $x\mapsto X(x)$. The ODE $(3)$ has a two-dimensional solution space of functions $x\mapsto X(x)$, whereby the concrete expression of these solutions depends on the value of $\lambda$. One then has to confront the resulting expressions with the boundary conditions, and it turns out that for certain "special" values of $\lambda$ usable solutions $x\mapsto X_\lambda(x)$ result. Etcetera.

Answer (score 3):

Back up one step from $(1)$, to $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ and the PDE implies $$XT'=kX''T.\tag{0}$$ Now, when you divide through by $kX(x)T(t)$ in $(0)$, we are making the implicit assumption that we are not doing so when $X(x)=0$ or $T(t)=0$. The only way this is impossible is if $X(x)\equiv 0$ or $T(t)\equiv 0$ but either of those in turn cause $u(x,t)\equiv 0$ and such a $u$ won't satisfy any interesting initial conditions. In other words, at the outset, we declare that we are looking for nontrivial (not identically zero) solutions.

Now, *even under that assumption*, how is it valid to go from $(0)$ to $(1)$? Well, it must mean that we are performing that division for values of $x$ for which $X(x)\not=0$ and values of $t$ for which $T(t)\not=0$. That is,
$${X''(x)\over X(x)}={T'(t)\over k T(t)}=-\lambda, \qquad \forall x,t\text{ such that }X(t)\not=0,\ T(t)\not=0.\tag{2}$$
Proceeding from there, you find the solution to the IBVP subject to the $x$, $t$ condition in $(2)$.

But what about $Z:=\{(x,t):X(x)=0\text{ or }T(t)=0\}$? Suppose $X(x^*)=0$, i.e. $(x^*,t)\in Z$, where the zero occurs in $X$ rather than $T$. Then $u(x^*,t)=X(x^*)T(t)$ and since we are assuming a solution of the form $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$, then 
\begin{align}
0&=u_t(x^*,t)-ku_{xx}(x^*,t)\\
0&=X(x^*)T(t)-kX''(x^*)T(t)\\
0&=0\cdot T(t)-kX''(x^*)T(t)\\
0&=X''(x^*)T(t)
\end{align}
so either $X''(x^*)=0$ or $T(t)=0$ *for all* $t$. Either way, $(0)$ holds at that $(x^*,t)\in Z$. A similar argument shows $(0)$ is also satisfied for $(x,t^*)\in Z$. So 
we know what the solution is on $Z$. The rest of the work in the separation of variables method is to find $u(x,t)$ for $(x,t)\not\in Z$.

So in your sample problem we end up with the sequence of eigenvalues and eigenfunctions $$\lambda_n=\left({n\pi\over L}\right)^2, \qquad X_n(x)=\sin(n\pi x/L), \qquad n=1,2,\dots$$
Since $T_n(t)=Ce^{-\lambda_n k t}$, the $T_n(t)$ never vanish (and thus make no contribution to the set $Z$), but the number of zeros of $X_n(x)$ *increases* with $n$.

For example, 
$$
n=2,\ L=1,\ x={1\over 2}\implies X_2(1/2)=\sin((2\pi\cdot {1\over 2})/1)=\sin(\pi)=0.
$$

Is this problematic? Well, let's finish the process. Recall that in light of having found these sequences $X_n(x)$, $T_n(t)$, $n=1,2,\dots$, what we have found is a solution $$u_n(x,t)=X_n(x)T_n(t) \text{ for each fixed }n=1,2,\dots$$ 
Then we superimpose to find the solution
$$
u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_nX_n(x)T_n(t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n \sin(n\pi x/L)e^{-\lambda_n k t}.
$$

Indeed,
$$u_2(1/2,t)=X_2(1/2)T_2(t)=0,$$ 
*but that doesn't make $u(1/2,t)$ vanish* since not all the $X_n(x)$ vanish at $x=1/2$.

To summarize: for each fixed $n=1,2,\dots$ there is a set 
$$
Z_n:=\{(x,t): 0<x<L\text{ and } t>0;\ X_n(x)=0\text{ or }T_n(t)=0\}.
$$
For each fixed $n$, on $Z_{n}$, $u_{n}(x,t)$ vanishes from $(0)$, without appealing to $(1)$. However, this does not mean $u(x,t)$ vanishes since $u_m(x,t)$, $m\not={n}$ don't all vanish. As for the $(x,t)\not\in Z_n$ (but in our domain), it is precisely for those $(x,t)$ pairs that we apply $(2)$.

Now you can see why we needed $X(t)$ and $T(t)$ *not identically* zero: it leaves room for us to implement the plan in the last paragraph.